# MacPorts Vim prefixes $PATH with /etc/paths

Tags: vim, path, macports

For some reason it seems that vim (installed through macports: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 25 2013 01:56:26`) prefixes my $PATH variable with the /etc/paths files.

Although I don't mind it adding those, it is very convenient that it is **prefixing** my path with that in all cases in a way that I cannot override it (or at least, I haven't found a way to do so).

Example of the problem:

```
" First we overwrite $PATH with something to show the problem
:let $PATH='just_some_non_existing_dir'

" Now print the path in the shell to show the problem (note the !)
:!echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/texbin:just_some_non_existing_dir
```

How can I prevent Vim from prefixing this $PATH for every external command I execute?

A little information about my environment:

> OS X: 10.8.2
>   VIM: Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Feb 25 2013 01:56:26)
>   zsh: 4.3.11 (i386-apple-darwin12.0)

Note that I run zsh as a shell.

Comment: Does `:set shellcmdflag?` include `-l`? That would launch a login shell and source the profile again.

Comment: Vim is not the culprit. Your shell is.

Comment: @IngoKarkat: no, it's at the default `shellcmdflag=-c`

Comment: @romainl: How so? The path in my shell (before I type `vim`) doesn't include this (or at least, has different paths before this section)

Comment: After a little research from both your hints I found the problem, apparently the default behaviour of zsh is similar to `bash -l` cause it's overwriting my path with things from my local path settings. My shell was indeed the culprit, what I can't figure out is how this just changed recently. I never had this problem but I'm not sure when it changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the great help of @IngoKarkat and @romaini I found the solution. Here's some info for people to debug this problem:

```
# To figure out which shell Vim is executing:
:set shell
:set shellcmdflag
# The response of these 2 concatenated are what will be executed by Vim
```

Now, once you know what it's running, exit Vim and execute it in your local shell to see what the results are (in my case, "zsh -c"):

```
# zsh -c 'echo $PATH'
```

If this is wrong, it could be something in your `.zshrc`, `.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/zsh/zshrc`, `/etc/zshrc` or one of the many other files.